# How to get values of each row in a matrix according to the max and secondary values and indexes which I got from another matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to get  values of each row in a matrix according to the max and secondary value indexes which I got from another matrix in tensorflow? E.g. I have a matrix tensor A as

```
    [[1,2,3],
     [6,5,4],
     [7,9,8]],
```

and a Matrix tensor B

```
    [[10,11,12],
     [13,14,15],
     [16,17,18]].
```

Then I  get the maximum value and secondary maximum value index vector form matrix A like

```
    [[2,1],
     [0,2],
     [1,2]]
```

by using tf.nn_topk. Then I want to get the exatly value of matrix B from these index, which is

```
    [[12,11],
     [13,15],
     [17,18]].
```

How should I do? it seems maybe tf.gather_nd  can do this work, But I don't know how to give the generate the 2-D index for it.

Answer (score 2):

So for this specific case this code returns the values.

1. It isn't vectorized
2. It isn't generic

It just creates a template for `gather_nd` like this.

```
 [[0 1]
  [0 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 0]
  [2 2]
  [2 1]]
```

Others may have more compact ideas.

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.Variable([[10,11,12],
     [13,14,15],
     [16,17,18]], )

B = tf.Variable([[2,1],
     [0,2],
     [1,2]] )


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

indices =  sess.run(B)

incre = tf.Variable(0)
template = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([6,2],tf.int32))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#There are 3 rows in the indices array
row = tf.gather( indices , [0,1,2])


for i in range(0, row.get_shape()[0] ) :

    newrow = tf.gather(row, i)

    exprow1 = tf.concat([tf.constant([i]), newrow[1:]], axis=0)
    exprow2 = tf.concat([tf.constant([i]), newrow[:1]], axis=0)

    template = tf.scatter_update(template, incre, exprow1)
    template = tf.scatter_update(template, incre + 1, exprow2)

    #Dataflow execution dependency is enforced.
    with tf.control_dependencies([template]): 
        incre = tf.assign(incre,incre + 2)

print(sess.run(tf.gather_nd(A,template)))
```

Output is this.

```
[11 12 15 13 18 17]
```